# What would cause Julia to throw a warning and say that something cannot be imported?

Tags: julia

I am trying to get my unit tests for a private repo to run on Travis. However, I am getting the following error:

```
WARNING: could not import POMDPs.initial_state into PrivateRepo
850ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: UndefVarError: initial_state not defined
```

Edit to make things simpler: **what would cause Julia to throw a warning and say that something cannot be imported**?

Comment: It's almost impossible to guess without some code. If the code is private, can you at least come up with a MWE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) without any private code that results in this error which you can share?

Comment: updated to make this clearer. The real question I am trying to ask is above. I bogged it down initially with setup specific stuff, but the real question is why would Julia say that I cannot import something?

Comment: This typically means that the symbol (`initial_state`) does not exist within the module (`POMDPs`).  Double-check the version that gets installed on Travis, to make sure that the symbol exists and is available at that location (e.g. make sure it's available as `POMDPs.initial_state`, and not `POMDPs.Util.initial_state` or something like that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue did not end up being as sinister as I guessed. It turns out my Julia 1.0.3 environment had a different version of `POMDPs` than my PrivateRepo's `Manifest.jl` file. All I did to fix it was downgrade `POMDP's` and a couple of packages that depended upon the newer version of `POMDP's`.